# Why autolayout is very inconsistent sometimes

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, constraints, ios-autolayout

I had a view controller and some textviews and I am setting the textviews height dynamically using height constraint constant I set the the problem of inconsistency came at setting the height for two textviews...

One day I set its height for different devices(iPhone 4s,iPhone 5s,iphone 6s, iphone6s plus) and it was working fine for these devices but.. next day it wasn't working then I had to set the height constants again..

I am wondering how come this could happen ? why it worked previous day and why I had to change again ?

its very confusing this particular incident made me lose confidence on autolayout in xamarin.ios itself ?

Earlier some thing like this happened for one of the view's top constraint..

Please somebody tell me if there are any other things I have to be aware when it comes to autolayout in xamarin.ios ...

Please somebody clarify

Answer (score 0):

Maybe first time you tested your app "AutoLayout" was enabled in storyboard, but at second time it was disabled.

Please check the link below and check the paragraph about enabling/disabling the "AutoLayout" property.

Comment: there is no link

Comment: Sorry I made that typo. Here is the link:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/designer_auto_layout/

Comment: It has been enabled before the incident as well

Comment: Are you still facing that issue?

Comment: it was a thing of past .. i mean to say .. when i facd the inconsistency i had it enabled ... i am wondering why would it happen

Comment: I am using xcode to design UI for Autolayout ... is it not advisable ?

Comment: Xcode is just a tool, if that is convenient for to you to use then why not? And if you ask what I'll prefer, I'll surely prefer Xcode; because I am using Xcode since the beginning.

Comment: But such inconsistency sometimes... thats what I am wondering